# Error when trying to connect to API in Azure but origin is allowed

Tags: node.js, azure, express, cors

So, I have two web apps in Azure, one is the frontend and one is an API. The frontend connects with the API through this code:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsuarioService {

  uri = 'https://myazureapi.azurewebsites.net';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(usuario:string, senha:string){
    const Usuario ={
      usuario:usuario,
      senha:senha
    }
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.uri}/login`, Usuario);
  }
}
```

And in the API, I have this, with User being a mongoose model:

```
const Express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const BodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port=process.env.PORT||3000;
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var app = Express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 
    "https://myazureapplication.azurerewebsites.net");
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
      return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
  });

const router = Express.Router();
app.use(BodyParser.json());
app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.connect("mymongodatabase");
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', () => {
   console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully!');
});

router.route('/login').post((req, res)=>{
     let usuarioData = new User(req.body);
     User.findOne({usuario:usuarioData.usuario}, (err, usuario)=>{
       if(err){
            return next(new Error('Could not load document')); 
       }else{
            if(!usuario ||(usuario.senha!==usuarioData.senha)){
                res.status(401).send('Email ou senha inválida')
            }else{
                res.status(200).send(usuario);
            }
       }
   });
});
```

Sure enough, when I run both he API and the frontend locally it works like a charm, but when I deploy the API, I get a "CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing" error. Do I need something more since its on cloud? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Newest

Don't need to configure it in code.

[image]

You just configure `CORS` in portal, you can achieve the same function.

[image]

If you just want `https://myazureapplication.azurerewebsites.net` access, you can add it. For all, just add `*`.

**PRIVIOUS**

Please use this code to allow all websites to access the api for testing. Make sure that the URL you specify `https://myazureapplication.azurerewebsites.net` is not wrong.

```
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.header("X-Powered-By",' 3.2.1')
  res.header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
  next();
});
```